# First-order formula implying the existence of an infinite branch in a tree

Tags: first-order-logic, infinity, trees

I want to find a formula which would imply the existence of an infinite branch in a tree. I know beforehand that my tree has countably many vertices (in fact, each vertex can possibly have a countable number of sons, so we cannot directly apply the Kőnig's lemma).

My question is: quantifying only over vertices (and edges, for that matter), is it possible to write a logical formula showing that the tree has an infinite branch (*i.e.* a tree satisfies the formula iff it has an infinite branch) ?
It is not hard to find one implying the existence of branches of arbitrary length, but this is not what I am looking for - although I am not even sure such a property can be expressed in first-order logic.

If this is impossible, are there some other assumptions that would need to be made in order to be able to write such a formula ? (For example, if the tree had a finite branching factor - which can be expressed by a first-order formula - then we could apply the Kőnig's lemma. As I already said, this is not the case here, but does there exist other hypothesis that would achieve the same result ?)

Comment: dear Numbra; what first order language are you working in? surely this will very much affect the answer... (for example, what is the formula that implies the existence of arbitrarily large branches? (+1)

Answer (score 1):

As it stands out, there is no easy way to answer my question. Indeed, one can find
[here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eharel/SCANNED.PAPERS/EffectiveTransformations.pdf) some sets of trees in term that are placed in the *analytic* hierarchy - rather than the arithmetic one, and I do not have any way of "discarding" those trees with the elements given in my question, meaning that the general problem is much harder that what can be dealt with FO-logic.